# Clearing the form input fields

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

[![output image][1]][1]

I have made a webpage in which I am reading data from a JSON file and displaying it. I am also taking input from input fields and  displaying it along with the previous data. But when I click on submit button, the input fields does not get cleared and still have the previous input data. I am resetting the fields but still it's not working.

Here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="Provider List">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Provider's List</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "script/script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="Controller">
<div class="container">
 <div class="title">
     <h1>Provider Directory</h1>
     <h5>v2.0</h5>
</div>
<div class="tableDiv">
    <div class="providerList">
        <p>Provider List</p>
    </div>
<table style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th ng-click="sortData('last_name')">Last Name <div ng-class="getSortClass('last_name')"></div> </th>
        <th ng-click="sortData('first_name')">First Name <div ng-class="getSortClass('first_name')"></div> </th>
        <th ng-click="sortData('email_address')">Email <div ng-class="getSortClass('email_address')"></div> </th>
        <th ng-click="sortData('specialty')">Specialty <div ng-class="getSortClass('specialty')"></div> </th>
        <th ng-click="sortData('practice_name')">Practice Name <div ng-class="getSortClass('practice_name')"></div> </th>
        <th ng-click="">Delete</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="peoples in people | orderBy:sortColumn:reverseSort">
            <td>{{peoples.last_name}}</td>
            <td>{{peoples.first_name}}</td>
            <td>{{peoples.email_address}}</td>
            <td>{{peoples.specialty}}</td>
            <td>{{peoples.practice_name}}</td>
            <td><input type="button"  value = "Delete" text = "Button" data-ng-click="removeRow($index)"/> </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>

<div class="quickaddForm">

<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="addRow()">
    <label>Create Provider</label>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name"
               ng-model="last_name" required />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">First Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name"
                   ng-model="first_name"required/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email_address"
                   ng-model="email_address" required />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Specialty</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="specialty"
                   ng-model="specialty" required />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Practice</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="practice_name"
                   ng-model="practice_name"  required/>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div style="padding-left:130px; padding-top:20px">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

And Here is JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
 var ProviderList = angular.module('Provider List', []);
 ProviderList.controller('Controller', function ($scope, $http){
/*
Reading the data from JSON file
*/
$http.get('people.json').success(function(data) {
    $scope.people = data.people;
    $scope.sortColumn="LastName"
    $scope.reverseSort = false;
    /*
    Sorting the selected column by clicking on the table heading
    */
    $scope.sortData = function (column) {
        $scope.reverseSort = ($scope.sortColumn == column) ? !$scope.reverseSort : false;
        $scope.sortColumn = column;
    }

    $scope.getSortClass = function (column) {
        if ($scope.sortColumn == column) {
            return $scope.reverseSort ? 'arrow-down' : 'arrow-up';
        } return ''; 
    }

    /*
    Adding the data in JSON format which was entered in the form fields
    */    
    $scope.addRow = function(){
        $scope.people.push({ 'last_name':$scope.last_name,
                     'first_name': $scope.first_name,
                     'email_address':$scope.email_address,
                     'specialty' :$scope.specialty,
                     'practice_name': $scope.practice_name
        });

        /*
        To clear the input fields once SUBMIT button is clicked.
        */
        $scope.people.last_name=' ';
        $scope.people.first_name=' ';
        $scope.people.email_address='';
        $scope.people.specialty='';
        $scope.people.practice_name='';

    };

    /*
    Removing the selected row by clicking the delete button.
    */
    $scope.removeRow = function (idx) {
    $scope.people.splice(idx, 1);
    };
});
});
```

Comment: Need to see HTML to solve this, your back end code has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: i have updated my code. Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding your inputs with `$scope` variables so the inputs will be always having the values in your controller, so you need to reset these values in your controller.

And here in your code you are clearing the wrong variables:

```
$scope.people.last_name=' ';
$scope.people.first_name=' ';
$scope.people.email_address='';
$scope.people.specialty='';
$scope.people.practice_name='';
```

You need to clear the binded variables without `.people`, because you are just clearing variables inside your `people` object here.

So that's what you need:

```
$scope.last_name='';
$scope.first_name='';
$scope.email_address='';
$scope.specialty='';
$scope.practice_name='';
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I tried your method but it is still not working on my end.I have added javascript code in my question. Can you please have a look at it and let me know where i am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First add a name for your form, say myForm (not a must if you are not using AngularJS's form validation).

```
<form name="myForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" ng-submit="addRow()"></form>
```

Under the `addRow()` method in your Angular controller, manually reset all data model values and `$setPristine()`.

```
$scope.addRow = function() {
  // Your codes to submit the data to server
  // ...

  // Manual Reset
  $scope.first_name = '';
  $scope.last_name = '';

  // Set Form Pristine (Not a must if you are not using AngularJS's form validation)
  $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I tried your method but it is still not working on my end.I have added java-script code in my question. Can you please have a look at it and let me know where i am going wrong. Thanks in advance.